# MS Word 2003 VBA Deleting a graphic object

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that generates a case label for a list of different products. Some of the products are sterile and require a drawing of a circle to be placed on the label as a location for a radiation indicator dot. There is also a text box inside the circle that labels the circle as the location for the dot.  I tried to do this by inserting an autoshape of a circle and making it a bookmark and then using the code:

```
ThisDocument.Bookmarks("GammaDot").Range.Delete
```

to delete the circle on all the parts that aren't sterile.  This code works to delete the text from the text box inside the circle, but the circle itself doesn't get deleted.
It also seems that the text box itself isn't getting deleted, just the text inside the box.  Does the bookmarks.Delete command not work on actual obects? and if it doesn't, how would I go about deleting the circle and text box?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you will have to either delete the shapes by name or in a loop. The bookmark parent returns the document, not the textbox. This will delete both the textbox and the circle:

```
For i = ThisDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    ''Debug.Print ThisDocument.Shapes(1).Name
    ThisDocument.Shapes(i).Delete
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get hold of the shapes belonging to a bookmark using the ShapeRange property of the bookmark's Range, and the shape's text using its TextFrame:

```
Dim bkmk As Bookmark
Set bkmk = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("circle")
Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = bkmk.Range.ShapeRange.Item(1)
Debug.Print shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
shp.Delete
```

Deleting the shape will also remove the contained text.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete everything except text and its formatting by running following code in vba editor:

Sub DeleteAllExceptText()

```
Dim i As Integer

With ActiveDocument
    For i = .Tables.Count To 1 Step -1
        .Tables(i).Delete
    Next i
End With

Dim j As Integer

With ActiveDocument
    For j = .Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        .Shapes(j).Delete
    Next j

Dim k As Integer

With ActiveDocument
    For k = .InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        .InlineShapes(k).Delete
    Next k
```

End Sub